# Cannot get any facebook permissions with C# facebook SDK 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a fairly simple site which allow users to connect via facebook.

I am using C# facebook sdk MVC.

At first i didn't need any specific permission so there were no problems for users to connect. my code looked like this

```
public class FacebookController : BaseController
{
    public FacebookSession FacebookSession
    {
        get { return (new CanvasAuthorizer().Session); }
    }
    public ActionResult Profile()
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient(this.FacebookSession.AccessToken);
        dynamic me = client.Get("me");
        ViewBag.Name = me.name;
        ViewBag.Id = me.id;
        return View();
    }
}
```

and on my webconfig

```
<facebookSettings appId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" appSecret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

After a while I needed more specific permissions so I added CanvasAuthorize to my action - as so

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "user_about_me,user_relationships,email,publish_stream")]
public ActionResult Profile()
```

That got me this exception:
Exception Details: System.Exception: CanvasUrl is null or empty

So I added to my Webconfig the canvasUrl which got me the same error with out the canvasPage So now my web config has all 4

```
<facebookSettings appId="XXXXXXXXXX" appSecret="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx" canvasUrl = "http://localhost:60606/" canvasPage = "https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/"/>
```

So now my user can log in via facebook, my problem is that when he does log in he is getting redirect to my Facebook app (**http://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXXXX/facebook/profile**)

instead back to my site(**http://localhost:60606/facebook/profile**)

How can I get the Permissions that i need and redirect my user back to my site after he logs in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, My bad

CanvasAuthorize is just as it sounds, authorization for canvas.
So you cannot use it without an app canvas on facebook.

What I should have done is use the FacebookOAuthClient

```
var oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
var loginUri = oAuthClient.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "state", null }, { "scope", "user_about_me,user_relationships,email" } });
return Redirect(loginUri.AbsoluteUri);
```